# Issue with large size images in HTTP Post

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, ios7.1

See my code which i used to post image in Web server. I can send small size image. but its not working for the large size images. Where i should modify this code to enable large size images

```
 NSString *requestString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UserId=%@&CategoryId=%@&Continent=%@&Country=%@&City=%@&Gender=%@&ImageName=%@&AgeRange=%@",UserId,CategoryId,continentTextfield.text,countrytextfield.text,citytextfield.text,gender,imagename,ageTextfield.text];

NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.2.4:98/UserImage.svc/InsertFacialImage?%@",requestString];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// Create 'POST' MutableRequest with Data and Other Image Attachment.


NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(chosenImage);

//  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(chosenImage)];
[request addValue:@"image/png" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Ret: %@",returnString);


NSURLConnection *connReq = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
 if (connReq)
 {

    NSLog(@"Connection Sucessful");


}

else {

    NSLog(@"failed");

}

[connReq start];
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896465/uploading-big-image-in-background-thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGFloat compr = 0.9f;    //comress the size of the image
CGFloat maxCompre = 0.1f;  //max allowed compression from 0 to 1
int maxSize = 250*1024;   //max file size 

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, compr);

while ([imageData length] > maxSize && compr > maxCompre)
{
compr -= 0.1;
imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, compression);  //compress the size
}
```

finally u pass the `imageData` to the server

Comment: karthik  its not working.. getting error, response 413

Comment: then simple think just use this imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 0.2f);

Comment: is anyway for UIImagePNGRepresentation